# Camel Casing and Underscore addition in filename with text, number and date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, camelcasing

Relatively new with python and pandas, hence need some inputs here. Appreciate some response here.
I'm having multiple files with a filename having a combination of text, number and date. I want to have ***camel casing with an underscore and trimming of white space*** to a standard format, for eg,

FileName- **ARA Inoc Start Times V34 20200418**.xlsx to be named as **Ara_Inoc_Start_Time_V34_20200418.xlsx**

FileName- **Batch Start Time V3 20200418.xlsx** to be named as **Batch_Start_Time_V3_20200418.xlsx**

The challenge I'm facing is 
1) how to add an underscore before date?
2) with a word in a filename like ARA Inoc Start - my code converts it to A_R_A _Inoc _Start. How to adapt it to Ara_Inoc? this would involve trimming the white space as well. How to add it in current code.

```
def change_case(str): 
    res = [str[0].upper()] 
    for c in str[1:]: 
        if c in ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'): 
            res.append('_') 
            res.append(c.upper()) 
        else: 
            res.append(c) 

    return ''.join(res) 

# Driver code 

for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\t\\Documents\\DummyData\\"):
    str = filename
    print(change_case(str))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the strings using `str.split()`, convert the first letter using `str.upper()`, then join them using `str.join()`

```
import os
for filename in [
    ' ARA Inoc Start Times V34 20200418.xlsx  ', 
    ' Batch_Start_Time_V3_20200418.xlsx '
]:  #  os.listdir('C:\\Users\\t\\Documents\\DummyData\\')
    new_filename = '_'.join([i[:1].upper()+i[1:].lower() for i in filename.strip().split()])
    print(new_filename)
```

Output:

```
Ara_Inoc_Start_Times_V34_20200418.xlsx
Batch_start_time_v3_20200418.xlsx
```

Note the use of `i[:1].upper()+i[1:]` instead of `str.title()`. You can use the latter, but that will convert the file extension to title case as well, hence why I used the above instead. Alternatively, you can split the filename and the extension before doing the conversion:

```
import os
for filename in[
    ' ARA Inoc Start Times V34 20200418.xlsx  ', 
    ' Batch_Start_Time_V3_20200418.xlsx '
]:
    filename, ext = filename.rsplit('.', 1)
    filename = '_'.join([i.title() for i in filename.strip().lower().split()])
    new_filename = '.'.join([filename, ext])
    print(new_filename)
```

Output:

```
Ara_Inoc_Start_Times_V34_20200418.xlsx  
Batch_Start_Time_V3_20200418.xlsx
```